# C#: Problem receiving UDP packet from device connected via mobile hotspot

Tags: c#, udp, hotspot

I'm having a problem with simple UDP packet receive from a device connected remotely via Windows mobile hotspot.

The device (an esp32 wifi board) connects to the laptop via wifi, DHCP parameters are all received correctly. The device is correctly sending packets to the laptop, which I can see in wireshark. The packets show the ip of the device (192.168.137.xx sending to 192.168.137.1 port 4444). A testprogram "UDP Sender-Recevier" from Microsoft store is able to receive the packets when configured to listen on port 4444.

The problem now is that the program that is intended to receive the packets does not seem to see them. The listener thread basically looks like this:

```
       public void serverThread()
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(4444);
            while (true)
            {
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                // do something with received string 
            }
        }
```

When running it starts the server, but `receiveBytes` never gets the message the remote device is sending. Interestingly enough, using a testprogram called "PacketSender" to send something to port 4444 on the PC locally works, the message is received.

I suppose there is some issue with packages being received from the hotspot side of the network. Since UDP Sender-Receiver gets the message, I think it should be possible from within the C# application as well, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Reiner

Added information to original post:
Here is some data collected by wireshark. These four packets are observed when the program starts: 1 is the initial message send by my program to the external device, 2 and 3 are ARP related, apparently the device requests and receives the MAC address of the PC interface, 4 is the answer coming back from the device to the local PC. This answer is never received by the udpClient listening on port 4444 (listening on 0.0.0.0:4444 according to netstat):

```
1   0.000000    192.168.137.1   192.168.137.255 UDP 43  60138 → 3333 Len=1
2   0.374833    Espressi_66:95:58   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.137.1? Tell 192.168.137.251
3   0.374882    e6:a7:a0:8e:1e:bc   Espressi_66:95:58   ARP 42  192.168.137.1 is at e6:a7:a0:8e:1e:bc
4   0.377677    192.168.137.251 192.168.137.1   UDP 48  3333 → 4444 Len=6
```

Following is the complete dump of packages 1 (from program to device) and 4 (from device to program):

```
Frame 1: 43 bytes on wire (344 bits), 43 bytes captured (344 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{B71E40C1-C840-4749-B189-3646E2B2A741}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: e6:a7:a0:8e:1e:bc (e6:a7:a0:8e:1e:bc), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.137.1, Dst: 192.168.137.255
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 60138, Dst Port: 3333
Data (1 byte)

Frame 4: 48 bytes on wire (384 bits), 48 bytes captured (384 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{B71E40C1-C840-4749-B189-3646E2B2A741}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Espressi_66:95:58 (08:3a:f2:66:95:58), Dst: e6:a7:a0:8e:1e:bc (e6:a7:a0:8e:1e:bc)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.137.251, Dst: 192.168.137.1
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 3333, Dst Port: 4444
Data (6 bytes)
```

Comment: Is the application running on the loopback interface (you see "127.0.0.1") ?

Comment: No, it isn't. The other direction works, my application is able to send packages via UDP to the external device, but receiving does not work.

Comment: If you run the nestat command you see 0.0.0.0:4444 ?

Comment: just tried that out. Yes, I do see 0.0.0.0:4444 in both cases. That is when UDP Sender Receiver is connected (which does receive the message) and also when my program is connected to the port (which does not receive the message).

Comment: BTW, don't know if it matters: Binding the listening port to the specific IP does not help either. In that case netstat is showing 192.168.137.1:4444, but the behaviour is unchanged.

Comment: I just noticed in the update you posted that your destination is 192.168.137.255 in the frame 1 and the source is 192.168.137.251 in the frame 2. Is it normal?

Comment: yes, that's intended. I am using the broadcast address on the initial send, since in the end there will be two identical devices connected which both shall receive the message. ...251 is the address assigned by DHCP on this particular connection (keeps changing with every connection to the mobile hotspot).

Comment: Is it the communication using the broadcast that is failing? Some operating systems do not answer to broadcast the address. Otherwise, it might be a firewall issue. which OS are you using?

Comment: no, the broadcast is going through to the device. The communication back to the PC is failing. Firewall can be excluded, it doesn't work with the firewall deactivated either. OS is windows 10 professional.

Comment: Can you change `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)` to `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4444)`. you must specify the source port there

Comment: does not change anything. Besides, all programming examples I found for the udpServer use the 0 there, after all, the IPEndPoint gets filled by the udpClient.receive method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not an answer in the sense that I can explain what went wrong, but a workaround!

When I make the udpServer thread send to the remote device before starting the while loop, it suddenly receives the data. Apparently it needs to establish contact once from this thread before it can receive.

Strange thing, but works.

Code now looks like this:

```
        public void serverThread()
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(4444);
            var address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.137.255"); 
            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, 3333);  
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testing");
            udpClient.Send(bytes, 7, ipEndPoint);
            while (true)
            {
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
// do something with received data here ...
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your support!

Reiner

Answer (score 0):

Check that the UDP packets sent have the source ip specified.
Specifying it for me solved the problem.